# how to export AD user list from non domain system

Tags: active-directory

I want to export AD user list but my system in not in that Domain. I do have Admin permission. its 2008 AD. I know we can pull the list using dsquery / dsget or get-ADuser but all works when we are running this in same domain.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the the following from an elevated command prompt:

```
runas /netonly /user:domain\adminUsername cmd.exe
```

(Adding a host entry for the domain name may help/be necessary)

Then run your dsquery command:

```
dsquery * domainroot -filter "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))" -attr samAccountName distinguishedName whenCreated whenChanged lastLogonTimestamp
```

It's also possible to connect with AD Users and Computers from the system that is not in the domain.

Run the following from an elevated command prompt:

```
runas /netonly /user:domain\adminUsername "mmc dsa.msc /server:domainControllerName"
```